# Facebook Details

Tags: facebook

I have a website where i want to get visitor's facebook info (if any) like his name, country, etc and insert into database. I am just looking for a simple way to get his fb info and insert into database, no redirection like facebook connect. Any clues?

Comment: I'm hoping the answer to this question will be "you can't", because otherwise the privacy implications are appalling.  I'll watch with interest those who know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could *technically* accomplish this -- and a few solutions come to mind, all involving some variation of screen-scraping -- you would be **violating the Facebook terms of service and US privacy law**.

You can accomplish this with Facebook Connect, and it does **not** require redirection to Facebook. It's just a simple pop-up window where the user enters their Facebook username/password. It's very easy, very elegant, and has the advantage of not landing you in prison. :-)

Comment: Storing user data isn't necessarily violating any laws, FB or otherwise - see http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data for their policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using facebook connect, you need to somehow get his Facebook ID and get his information from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

There is no way for you to get that information except if you know his Facebook ID.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook Platform policies,](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data) you can store/cache user data - with restrictions. I'll leave you to make sure you comply with them after reading through that link. So assuming you have done that:

To get the user data, you need to get them to authorise an application with the permissions you need.

Once you have done this, you can use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to retrieve information about the user. You can experiment with Facebooks [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to test what permissions you require.

To to answer your question : A simple way would be to use the Facebook [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), and do an API call to https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID, for example https://graph.facebook.com/4 for Mark Zuckerberg